# ModuleNotFoundError 'matplotlib_inline'

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

As the title suggests, I am trying to set my notebook to plot in separate window using the '%matplotlib qt' command. However, when I do I get a 'ModuleNotFoundError' for matplotlib.inline for some reason. I have checked my env using 'pip list' and I have all the modules I need installed (I know this is the case because I have other environments for separate projects where %matplotlib qt works just fine and the module imports are identical.

Hoping for a suggestion that I haven't tried yet. pic of my import cell on current notebook:
[image: pic of my import cell on current notebook]

The problem seems to occur when I run the % command, even if I just run %matplotlib (without the qt) then I still get the same error. Could this be some sort of a path issue?

EDIT: I will add that if I remove the % command from my notebook I can plot just fine inline, but I don't have the plot tools to zoom in or move around which is the functionality I need to review my data.

Comment: Do you have the `qt` backend installed?  Did you try `%matplotlib --list`?  For zoom and pan, I usually use `%matplotlib notebook`.

Comment: Yes, and wouldn't work because: "The problem seems to occur when I run the % command, even if I just run %matplotlib (without the qt) then I still get the same error." For some reason, when I use the % command it doesn't see matplotlib.inline as being installed.